# What is the most efficient way to add data from one dataframe to another based on a common, recurring ID in R?

Tags: r, join, merge

I have a small dataframe with about 1000 entries that have unique IDs, along with some information associated with each ID.

```
id, type
ID1, A
ID2, B
ID3, C
ID4, A
ID5, B
```

I have a second very large dataframe where the IDs from the first frame are repeated in no particular order.

```
id
ID1
ID1
ID3
ID1
ID3
ID3
ID5
...
```

Given that the second frame is very large, I would like to know the most efficient way to add the 'type' from the first data frame to a new varible in the second, like so:

```
id
ID1, A
ID1, A
ID3, C
ID1, A
ID3, C
ID3, C
ID5, B
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `merge(df2, df1, all.x = TRUE)`. Note that your 2nd data.frame comes first.

Answer (score 0):

```r
merge(datB, datA, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
#    id type
# 1 ID1    A
# 2 ID1    A
# 3 ID1    A
# 4 ID3    C
# 5 ID3    C
# 6 ID3    C
# 7 ID5    B
```

(Order tends to be not-preserved; if that is needed, then I suggest there be some form of ordering column in the data.)

---

Data

```r
datA <- structure(list(id = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5"), type = c(" A", " B", " C", " A", " B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
datB <- structure(list(id = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID3", "ID1", "ID3", "ID3", "ID5")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```